# Sending a concatenated bytearray

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, security

I am trying to send data to username and password fields through a TCP socket. Using send() I need to use a byte object, which I understand. However, where I am stumped is I have tried using a byte array, I have tried appending "PASS ", buff and "\r\n" to the byte array but was not successful. I can't concatenate buff as its a string if I am using a byte literal. This is the code I originally have and need to change:

```
for buff in the buffer:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    conncet = sock.connect((target, port))
    sock.recv(2048)

    sock.send(b"USER test\r\n")
    sock.recv(2048)
    # The below code is where I've tried using a bytearray but I 
    # cannot get it to work
    sock.send(b"PASS " + buff + "\r\n") 
    sock.send(b"QUIT\r\n")
    sock.close()
```

Any suggestions and or help are appreciated.

Comment: `bytes` instances (such as `b"PASS"`) are not mutable; create a `bytearray` and add the arrays to that. Note that you forgot to convert the `b` in `b"\r\n"` as well.

Comment: Hi Maarten I have tried using a byte array but the application isnt recognising my data because it keeps looping when it should stop at a certain point. Is there an example you could share so that I can see your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are strings (sequences of *characters*) and there are bytes (sequences of *numbers*). Those two are fundamentally different things, but people tend to confuse them.

Strings can be represented as bytes. To do this, they need to be *encoded* in some way. To send them successfully through a TCP socket, the receiving end must know what encoding was used so it can convert the bytes back to string.

For example: The string "Hello World" could be represented as bytes through the ASCII encoding. These bytes would be:

```
72 101 108 108 111 32 87 111 114 108 100
```

Python would display those bytes as `b"Hello World"` to you, because `[72,101,108,108,111,32,87,111,114,108,100]` is so unwieldy. But the difference between `"Hello World"` and `b"Hello World"` is that the former is a list of characters, the latter is a list of numbers (!).

So what you need to do is

- pick an encoding (something like UTF-8, to accommodate international characters)
- encode the string into bytes
- send the bytes
- decode the bytes on the server

The client half of that

```
user_str = "test"
sock.send("USER " + user_str + "\r\n".encode('utf8'))

# ...

pass_str = "whatever"
sock.send("PASS " + pass_str + "\r\n".encode('utf8'))
```

Picking an encoding is the important part here. Don't skip that, or it will bite you.

Answer (score 1):

Try concatenating like this

`b"".join("provide the other part of the data here")`